# Translate a sentence in prolog

Tags: prolog, cpu-word, translate

can anyone help me to display untranslated word? for example i want to translate, 'i want to eat', in fact, there is no argument of to...so it will display 'saya mahu **to** makan'...the word **to** is remain the same it is and need to display it..this is the sample of my code..

```
:-dynamic(item/1).

kamus(saya,i).
kamus(suka,love).
kamus(awak,you).

run:-
  write('Enter a sentence:'),
  read(V),
  printed(V,C). 

%malay to eng

check(S,W,R):-
  kamus(R,S),name(S,W).

%eng to malay

check(S,W,R):-
  kamus(S,R),name(S,W).

check(Y,R):-
  item(Z),name(Z,Y).

try2(P,R):- 
  name(P,Q),
  split(Q,32,E),
  member(Z,E),
  assert(item(Z)),
  (check(Y,R);check(S,W,R)),Z=W.

printed(V,C):- 
  try2(V,C),write(C),write(' '),fail.

split(String, Space, [Word|List]) :-
  append(Word, [Space|Tail], String),
  !,
  split(Tail, Space, List).

split(String, _Space, [String]).
```

example of output:

```
?-run.
Enter the sentence : 'saya benci awak'.

i you no.
```

**there is no 'benci' in the fact but i need it to display in the output---> 'i benci you'

Answer (score 2):

try to add a 'catch-all' rule, after the cut addiction

```
check(S,W,R):-
  kamus(S,R),name(S,W), !.

% after edit. HTH    
check(S,_,R):-
  name(S,R).

check(Y,R):-
  item(Z),name(Z,Y), !.

check(Y,Y).
```

cuts ensure that the default in not engaged when there are more appropriate rules, listed in your rule db.

*edit*: I *didn't* noticed that the first check has arity **3** (then the first cut was useless). Of course *another* default should go where noted above.